# using JRebel in Eclipse RCP development

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jrebel

When developing a eclipse rcp applicatin,I need to restart the application after I changed my code.
My question is obviously should be this :
How can I use JRebel in RCP applition development, so I do not need to restart my whole big Application again and again ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had managed to do this, just install JRebel evaluation from Eclipse market, restart eclipse and configure JRebel, open your project's run configuration, you will see a JRebel tab, check "enable Jrebel agent", now JRebel will begin to save your much time.

---

some notes :

1. JRebel is not free, after a 30 days evaluation, you need to buy it.
2. sometimes you still need to restart your application, after removing a inner class for example, but I am not sure about this

Answer (score 0):

This may help: a JRebel plug-in that refreshes a bundle which's plugin.xml changes: https://bitbucket.org/toomasr/eclipse-jr-plugin (the bundle must have rebel.xml as well)